# Composition in c++ with raw or smart pointer?

Tags: c++, oop, smart-pointers, composition

A little example of what I want to do.

I have a list of (stack allocated) vertices

```
class Vertex {

    int id;
    double x;
    double y;
    double z;
};
```

and want to create a list of edges

```
class Edge {

    int id;
    Vertex * source;
    Vertex * target;
};
```

with two pointers to its source and target vertex.

Normally I would go for a reference here, but I want to be able to change the source or target vertex during runtime, so I need some kind of pointer type.

So my question: is there a smart pointer which would be useful here or should I just use a normal pointer as above?

**Edit**

Addressing some points, which came up in the answers:

First, the list should own the vertices, which is why they are on the stack.

Second, the ids are for an other program.

It needs a file with a list of all vertices and their coordinates, and a list of all edges and the ids of its two vertices.

Third, I need some kind of pointer, because the ids of the vertices change during runtime and the source and target vertex of a edge could change to.

(amongst other things some kind of cuts and slicing is performed)

Comment: What do you want the "smart pointer" to do?

Comment: How exactly do you expect a "list" of vertices to have the vertices "stack-allocated"? Surely you aren't talking about `std::list` then? Are you using some kind of custom `alloca()`-based allocator? That sounds pretty nightmarish...

Comment: list stands for any container, haven't yet decided which one is best. And stack allocated, because the vertices are not created with new.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### What Composition is

---

Composition *(in UML terms)* is an association when a given object is "a part" of another objects- i.e. it has the same lifetime and - what's most important and characteristic - *does not exist / make sense on its own*.

**According to this description, composition is not what we want to achieve - see the second part.**

In C or C++, the best way to implement composition is without using any pointers:

```
class Edge {

    int id;
    Vertex source;
    Vertex target;
};
```

This approach is best in terms of memory usage (one memory block for the whole object along with composite objects) and probably efficiency too. When you need composition - go for this solution.

### Why Composition isn't suitable for this problem

---

Composition implies some consequnces:

- The composed objects don't exist on their own,
- Their association with the composite object is permanent during that object's lifetime.

In your data model, you have separate:

- Array of vertices (independent),
- Array of edges.

Both possibly stack-allocated (but that's not really important).

Then you want each edge to **refer** to N vertices.

The edge does NOT own them - it only does refer to them. So neither composition, nor a smart pointer (which is designed to introduce some kind of ownership association) is not what you want here, because the design says that *the vertices are owned by the array of vertices, not by the edges*.

So go for a plain pointer.

**You could even use array indices instead of pointers** as an alternative (which indeed has its uses, e.g. if you'd want to use the latter array as an index buffer for 3D rendering). All depends on your needs.

Comment: One vertex will typically be used by at least 3 edges in 3D graphics work, so it won't be a space win (though it might still be faster due to locality).

Comment: Then you don't want to duplicate your vertices. And then, it's no longer composition - it's just association, so no strict ownership here.

Comment: Maybe association is the better description, but an (orientated) edge certainly "has a" source and a target vertex.

Comment: +1 for the edit, and I would suggest getting rid of everything prior to it as it's now a bit misleading.

Comment: @Randooom, that's true, but - in terms of OOP - composition can be described as "is-part-of" relationship. In this case, vertices are not "parts of" edges, so edges (edge objects) don't "consist of" vertices. The last part may sound counter-intuitive, but remember that we're referring to the *data model* now. In this context, the vertex objects are "parts of" the vertex array and not the edge objects.

Comment: @j_random_hacker, I'll rephrase the first part.

Comment: I don't think that the use of smart pointers necessarily "introduces some kind of ownership". Unless you think that `boost::weak_ptr` isn't also a smart pointer and that only the `boost::shared_ptr` s in such a system "count". (Of course, there isn't really a reason to use them here, but there could well be if, say, we had yet another class in the system whose instances could share `Vertex` instances...)

Comment: @Kos: another reason of using indices --> on 64 bits systems, a pointer is 64 bits, but you could perfectly use a 32 bits integer for the index. For frequent objects, saving off some bits might really impact the memory consumption / runtime of the application.

Comment: @Kos: Late to the game here, but what about unit testing a composition relationship. I don't know of a *good* way to give my tests access to the dependency (to make the right calls) without dependency injection, and I don't know how to inject a polymorphic dependency without using pointers. And the polymorphic part is important because I don't know how to validate the dependency without using a mock object upon which I can expect calls. Am I correct in thinking it's not feasible to unit test a class whose dependency is not a pointer?

Comment: Right, unit testability is a requirement that can complicate the design sometimes. But if you really care about how the object looks like in memory and want to stick with plain member fields, I'd say you could still unit-test it via static polymorphism rather than dynamic (e.g. make the class a template), maybe even conditional compilation.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, smart pointers are "smart" because they deal with the *ownership* issues involved. In the above, who do you want to *own* the vertices?

Answer (score 1):

Use a normal pointer. If the pointed-at objects are allocated on the stack, a smart pointer won't be all that helpful.

If you are concerned in the longer run about safety and bounds checking and so on, order each `Vertex` by its id (e.g., decide `0<=id<n`, then you can have an array of size `n`), and store the ids in the `Edge` rather than the pointers. Then you can use an `assert`, or whatever, to check that ids are in the legal range.

Answer (score 0):

It's a question of who owns the pointers. If your Edge class owns them then you can use an auto_ptr. However, you say that your Vertex objects are allocated on the stack so there's no real need for explicit clean-up in this scenario, as they'll be deleted when they go out of scope.

Comment: `auto_ptr` isn't a good idea here because more than 1 `Edge` will point to the same `Vertex` (assuming this is typical 3D graphics work).

Answer (score 0):

It's the usual tradeoff: a smart pointer will be safer but slower.  Use [Boost's `shared_ptr`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm) if you want to go that way.

For "business logic", I would strongly advocate using smart pointers.  But it looks like you may be doing CPU-intensive graphics processing, which is one of the cases where speed may be an important factor.  So I suggest:

```
//typedef Vertex *VertexPtr
typedef shared_ptr<Vertex> VertexPtr

class Edge {
    int id;
    VertexPtr source;
    VertexPtr target;
};
```

Use this for debugging, and switch the `//` when everything's working for a speed boost.

NOTE: If there is any possibility that a vertex may point back to an edge that points to it, things get more complicated -- you will need to use `weak_ptr` for one of the pointers to avoid circular references.

Comment: Of all smart pointers, why shared? Why introduce reference counting when you want strict ownership ...?

Comment: @j_random_hacker: Smart pointers aren't intrinsically "safer" -- it depends on how you use them. Different smart pointers encapsulate different ownership semantics -- you should use them when those are the semantics you want, not just because somebody told you that smart pointers are wonderful. They are incredibly helpful, but you shouldn't apply them blindly.

Comment: And on a separate note, switching between `Vertex*` and `shared_ptr<Vertex>` using a typedef is not a great idea -- they have different semantics, and the switch between the two will cause things to break in unexpected ways.

Comment: @Kos: What do you mean by "strict" ownership?  Do you mean that each vertex is owned by a unique edge?  Because I'm certain that's not the case here -- usually each vertex will be shared by >=3 edges.

Comment: A best approach here imho is that a vertex is not owned by any edge. There's a collection of vertices which *owns* vertices and a collection of edges which *refer* to vertices. No smart pointers needed.

Comment: @Stuart: Of course "it depends on how you use them".  What makes you think shared_ptr<T>'s ownership semantics are inappropriate here?  A vertex will be shared by several edges.  I agree that the `typedef` is weak, because it's insufficient -- there need to be wrappers for allocating and deallocating vertices as well.  With that in place, any operation that will break when switching from smart to plain pointers will break at compile time (e.g. calling `reset()`).  But I think Kos's latest suggestion is better in any case.

Comment: @j_random_hacker: I don't think that `shared_ptr` can't be made to work here, although I prefer the ownership strategy Kos suggests (i.e. edges do not own vertices). My point was merely that saying "a smart pointer will be safer but slower" rather oversimplifies the issue -- the implication of both that and the `typedef` you show below is that smart pointers and raw pointers are essentially interchangeable, which is not true because they have different semantics. I'm not saying you necessarily think that in reality (I'm sure you understand what's going on), but that's how it read.

Comment: Use a [Boost scoped_ptr](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/smart_ptr/scoped_ptr.htm) instead of a shared_ptr. "Simple sole ownership of single objects. Noncopyable."

Comment: @Sean: `scoped_ptr` is indeed underappreciated, but it's not the right tool for this job because a vertex is pointed to by more than one edge in general.  Using a `scoped_ptr` here would result in a vertex that belongs to k edges having its destructor called k times when the edge list is destroyed.